# Using gdcm (Grassroots DICOM) to Decompress DICOM Image Data

Tags: python, dicom, gdcm

Is it possible to use the Python wrappers for [GDCM](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net) to decode the image data in a DICOM file?

I have a `byte array` / `string` with the `bytes` of the image data in a DICOM file (i.e. the contents of tag `7fe0,0010` ("Pixel Data")) and I want to decode the image to something raw RGB or greyscale.

I am thinking of something along [the lines of this](https://github.com/neurosnap/mudicom/blob/72656a5638d10b59ea74e0fea257b1f9a9f250eb/mudicom/image.py#L32) but working with just the image data and not a path to the actual DICOM file itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can read the examples, there is one that shows how one can take an input compressed DICOM and convert it to an uncompressed one. See the code online here:

- [Decompress Image](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.8/html/DecompressImage_8py-example.xhtml)

If you are a big fan of NumPy, checkout:

- [This module add support for converting a gdcm.Image to a numpy array.](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.8/html/ConvertNumpy_8py-example.xhtml)

This is sort of a low level example, which shows how to retrieve that actual raw buffer of the image.

A much nicer class for handling `Transfer Syntax` conversion would be to use `gdcm.ImageChangeTransferSyntax` class (allow decompression of icon)

- [gdcm::ImageChangeTransferSyntax Class Reference](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.8/html/classgdcm_1_1ImageChangeTransferSyntax.xhtml)

If you do not mind reading a little C++, you can trivially convert the following code from C++ to Python:

- [Compress Image](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.8/html/CompressImage_8cxx-example.xhtml)

Pay attention that this example is actually **compressing** the image rather than **decompressing** it.

Finally if you really only have access to the data values contains in the Pixel Data attribute, then you should really have a look at (C# syntax should be close to Python syntax):

- [Decompress JPEG File](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.8/html/DecompressJPEGFile_8cs-example.xhtml)

This example shows how one can decompress a JPEG Lossless, Nonhierarchical, First- Order Prediction file. The JPEG data is read from file but it should work if the data is already in memory for your case.

Comment: Am I correct that in both of these examples, the contents of the file passed to `SetFileName` is a full DICOM file rather than just data from the `7fe0,0010` tag?